# Rails 3: Delete association duplicates from the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I've got these models:

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :guardian
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :relationships
  has_many :guardians, through: :relationships
end

class Guardian < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :relationships
  has_many :students, through: :relationships
end
```

I don't want any guardian to be related many times with one student. This can be prevented with a validation, but let's say it's too late and there are case where this is happening. For example, where `g` is a guardian:

```
g.relationships

[
    [0] #<Relationship:0x0000000bc33650> {
                          :id => 40321,
        :relationship_type_id => 2,
                  :student_id => 41700,
                 :guardian_id => 45820,
                  :created_at => Tue, 23 Apr 2013 17:44:29 UTC +00:00,
                  :updated_at => Tue, 23 Apr 2013 17:44:29 UTC +00:00,
    },
    [1] #<Relationship:0x0000000bc32e80> {
                          :id => 40923,
        :relationship_type_id => 2,
                  :student_id => 41700,
                 :guardian_id => 45820,
                  :created_at => Tue, 23 Apr 2013 18:58:46 UTC +00:00,
                  :updated_at => Tue, 23 Apr 2013 18:58:46 UTC +00:00,
    }
]
```

As you can see, these two relationships share the same student_id. I want to find out if there's a way I can delete from the database the duplicated relationships. I've tried the following lines of code to no avail:

```
g.relationships.uniq!(&:student_id)
g.update_attributes(relatioships: g.relationships.uniq!(&:student_id))
```

How can I solve this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Are there any rules about which of the duplicates should remain (most recent, earliest, something else), or it won't really matter?  Also, do you want SQL or ruby code for this?

Comment: No rules, if there are two of the same kind, any of them will work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
subquery = Relationship.select("student_id, guardian_id").
             group(:student_id, :guardian_id).
             having("count(*) > 1").to_sql
groups = Relationship.joins("JOIN (#{subquery}) sub ON relationships.student_id = sub.student_id AND relationships.guardian_id = sub.guardian_id").
                      group_by{|r| [r.student_id, r.guardian_id] }

groups.values.each do |duplicates|
  duplicates.drop(1).each(&:destroy)
end
```